# How to implode and keep value for each link?

Tags: php, arrays, implode

Say I have the following code:

```
$arr = array('id' => $tarr = array('1' => 'Fred', '2' => 'Wilma', 'c' => 'Bam Bam'));

echo '<a href="?tag='.$tarr.'">' . implode( '</a>, <a href="?tag='.$tarr.'">', $tarr) . '</a>';
```

This displays: Fred, Wilma, Bam Bam

but the `href` shows value `Array` instead of Fred for Fred, Wilma for Wilma etc

Cheers

Comment: I don't think that code snippet even makes sense. The issue you're having is that `$tarr` is an array, I'm assuming you want to do is use a foreach loop over `$tarr` and output a link for each name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build an output string (or array as shown here) using a foreach loop:

```
foreach($tarr as $v){
  $out[] = "<a href='?tag=$v'>$v</a>";
}

echo implode(', ', $out)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what youy are trying to do is this:

```
$arr = array('1' => 'Fred', '2' => 'Wilma', 'c' => 'Bam Bam');
echo '<a href="?tag='.implode('"></a><a href="?tag=',$arr).'"></a>';
```

Comment: I think we should be avoiding `implode` here and just use a for loop.  This code is way confusing.

Comment: this does not solve the problem that the value needs to be used as the text in the link, and the href attribute at the same time

Answer (score 0):

`$tarr` is an array, so when it's converted to a string, it prints `Array`.

Don't use `implode` here, you should use a for loop to get each value of the array.

What you should do is something like this:

```
$tarr = array('1' => 'Fred', '2' => 'Wilma', 'c' => 'Bam Bam');
$aTags = array();
foreach($tarr as $v){
  $aTags[] = '<a href="?tag='.$v.'">'.$v.'</a>';
}
echo implode(', ', $aTags);
```

Also, why do you have `$arr` here?  It's totally useless.

```
$arr = array('id' => $tarr = array('1' => 'Fred', '2' => 'Wilma', 'c' => 'Bam Bam'));
```

This is the same as:

```
$tarr = array('1' => 'Fred', '2' => 'Wilma', 'c' => 'Bam Bam');
$arr = array('id' => $tarr);
```